# Creating events on multiple calendars with FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar javascript library on my web site to display a calendar for each employee side-by-side. The calendar displays the Day view so it's easy to see everyones schedule for the day.

I have all of the calendars displaying properly side-by-side (each in their own div).

My problem is, when creating a new event by clicking on the calendar, the event always gets created on the last calendar on the page instead of the actual calendar you click on. I have a feeling it has to do with closure in the select callback function.

```
/*
*   Setup calendars for each sales person
*/
var d = $.fullCalendar.parseDate($("#requested_date").val());

//employee id numbers (each employee has own calendar)
var employees = new Array(445,123,999,444); 

for(i=0;i<employees.length;i++)
{
        var employeeId = employees[i];

        //clear any prevoius calendar info
        $('#calendar_' + employeeId).html("");

        calendar[employeeId] = $('#calendar_' + employeeId).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            year: d.getFullYear(),
            month: d.getMonth(),
            date: d.getDate(),
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            minTime: 7,
            maxTime: 19,
            height: 650,
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) { 

                calendar[employeeId].fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: "This Estimate",
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );

                calendar[employeeId].fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            events: {
                url: 'calendar/'+employees[employeeId],
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                        'personId': employees[employeeId],
                        'ci_csrf_token': wp_csr_value
                    },
                error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you select a calendar employeesId is equal to 444 so it render event on the last calendar try this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay , jsEvent ,view) { 
       $(view.element).parent().parent().fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: "This Estimate",
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );

                $(view.element).parent().parent().fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, but it pointed me in the right direction. The only thing your code was missing was to also include the jsEvent parameter according to [select_callback documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/). I did that, and your code works perfectly. Thanks for your help!